# Where should I register-resolve my types in a Console Application with Unity Container?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am a beginner to Unity DI Container.

I want to use it with a simple Console app.

I will use 'Code as Configuration'

Where should I call my method that Registers and Resolves my abstracts? From the Main method itself or there is a better, more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the concept of [Composition Roots](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). For a console app the `Main()` method is exactly the right place.

For Unity you can bundle your configuration in a class that derives from [UnityContainerExtension](http://goo.gl/00cZ5) and place the registration code inside the `Initialize()` method.

Then add your extension to the container.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian :) (As I have said before, I really enjoy reading your code ;) )

Comment: One example with UnityContainerExtension can be found here:
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.de/2009/09/custom-object-factory-unity-extension.html

Comment: @pencilCake The world is so small ;) Hope your project goes well!